# maven module on a module project

Tags: maven, module

Can a module of a modules maven project have is own module? how do you write the intermediate module pom? (here the pom of examples)
Somethink like that:

parent:

-> plugin1

-> -> pom.xml

-> plugin2

-> -> pom.xml

-> pom.xml :`<modules><module>plugin1</module><module>plugin2</module><module>examples</module> </modules>`

-> examples

-> -> example plugin1

-> -> -> pom.xml

-> -> example plugin2

-> -> -> pom.xml

-> ->  example plugin 1 & 2

-> -> pom.xml 
    `<modules><module>example plugin1</module><module>exampleplugin2</module><module>example plugin1 &2</module> </modules>`

Answer (score 1):

Any project with modules (in your case parent and examples), must be of packaging type pom and can define zero, one or multiple modules.

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
  <module>example-plugin1</module>
  <module>example-plugin2</module>
</modules>
```

Have a look at the [Camunda BPM Platform project](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform) on Github.
It also has a parent project, in this case the [BPM platform Pom](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform/blob/master/pom.xml) on the root of the repository. If you look at this pom, you will see one module named **engine-plugins**. The module itself is the parent of several modules (in this case Camunda BPM plugins). Therefore has the packaging type **pom**. Please see following pom.xml, since it is very similar to your example: https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform/tree/master/engine-plugins